# SQL server conditional join

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql, sql-server

I have to choose the according column to join basing on a value that can be null.
In detail:

```
SELECT shoporders.orderid, 
   shopaddresses.companyname, 
   shopaddresses.firstname, 
   shopaddresses.lastname, 
   shopaddresses.address1,  
FROM   shoporders 
   INNER JOIN shopaddresses 
           ON shoporders.InvoiceAddressId = shopaddresses.addressid
where orderid = 110
order by shoporders.createddate desc
```

if shoporders.InvoiceAddressId is null then I have to use shoporders.DeliveryAddressId

Any clue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ON coalesce(shoporders.InvoiceAddressId, shoporders.DeliveryAddressId) = shopaddresses.addressid
```

Answer (score 3):

you could try

```
SELECT shoporders.orderid, 
   shopaddresses.companyname, 
   shopaddresses.firstname, 
   shopaddresses.lastname, 
   shopaddresses.address1,  
FROM   shoporders 
   INNER JOIN shopaddresses 
           ON COALESCE (shoporders.InvoiceAddressId, shoporders.DeliveryAddressId)  = shopaddresses.addressid
where orderid = 110
order by shoporders.createddate desc
```

**Edit:** For a definition of coalesce see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx). A Summary below

Returns the first nonnull expression among its arguments. `COALESCE(expression1,...n)` is equivalent to the following `CASE` expression:

```
CASE

   WHEN (expression1 IS NOT NULL) THEN expression1

   WHEN (expression2 IS NOT NULL) THEN expression2

   ...

   ELSE expressionN

END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
 SELECT shoporders.orderid, 
       shopaddresses.companyname, 
       shopaddresses.firstname, 
       shopaddresses.lastname, 
       shopaddresses.address1,  
       FROM   shoporders 
       INNER JOIN shopaddresses 
       ON( 
          (shoporders.InvoiceAddressId IS NOT NULL  
                  AND shoporders.InvoiceAddressId = shopaddresses.addressid)
          OR (shoporders.DeliveryAddressId = shopaddresses.addressid) 
          )

       WHERE orderid = 110
       ORDER BY shoporders.createddate DESC
```