# Conditional joins in MS SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to do what I would think is a simple conditional join and I saw this ([SQL server conditional join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585746/sql-server-conditional-join)) which is CLOSE but not quite what I need.  I'm poor at explaining so I'll do my best to explain by example.

```
Device Table: (dev_tbl)
dev_id    dev_ip         name
1         192.168.1.10   Core_SW_1
2         192.168.20.5   Access_SW_1
3         192.168.240.1  Remote_SW_1

Additional Data Table: (dev_append)
id   append_id  dev_id  append_value
1    8          1       123 Rosebud Ln.
2    9          1       a.person
3    10         1       admin
4    8          3       2500 National Pkwy
5    9          3       my.self
6    10         3       some.user

Additional Data Defaults: (dev_append_def)
id   append_id    field_name   default_value
1    8            Address      NoClue
2    9            dev_owner    a.person
3    10           audit_by     nobody
```

Current SQL Query:

```
SELECT dev_tbl.dev_ip, dev_tbl.dev_name, dev_append.append_value, dev_append_def.field_name
FROM dev_tbl 
LEFT JOIN dev_append ON (dev_tbl.dev_id = dev_append.dev_id) 
RIGHT JOIN dev_append_def ON (dev_append.append_id = dev_append_def.append_id)
```

The above code give me all of the necessary information when there is an entry in dev_append, but as you can see it returns a single "null" entry for the device that does not have one.

```
192.168.1.10   Core_SW_1    123 Rosebud Ln.     Address
192.168.1.10   Core_SW_1    a.person            dev_owner
192.168.1.10   Core_SW_1    admin               audit_by
192.168.20.5   Access_SW_1  NULL                NULL
192.168.240.1  Remote_SW_1  2500 National Pkwy  Address
192.168.240.1  Remote_SW_1  my.self             dev_owner
192.168.240.1  Remote_SW_1  some.user           audit_by
```

My hangup is I need to get the field_name and default_value from dev_append_def *IF* there is no device specific entry in dev_append so the output would look like the below.

```
192.168.1.10   Core_SW_1    123 Rosebud Ln.     Address
192.168.1.10   Core_SW_1    a.person            dev_owner
192.168.1.10   Core_SW_1    admin               audit_by
192.168.20.5   Access_SW_1  NoClue              Address
192.168.20.5   Access_SW_1  a.person            dev_owner
192.168.20.5   Access_SW_1  nobody              audit_by
192.168.240.1  Remote_SW_1  2500 National Pkwy  Address
192.168.240.1  Remote_SW_1  my.self             dev_owner
192.168.240.1  Remote_SW_1  some.user           audit_by
```

I would simply do this, as I normally do, in a program with arrays but I would like to create a database view with this information.  If it cannot be done, that's all fine and well as well and I'll break out a Java app or PHP webpage.

Comment: Shouldn't that Right join be a left join?

Comment: It SHOULDN'T matter in this particular case, but that's an excellent point if I get unusual results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a cartesian product of all possible rows and then join for available values.

```
SELECT d.dev_ip, 
    d.dev_name, 
    COALESCE( d.append_value, dad.default_value) AS append_value,
    dad.field_name
FROM dev_tbl d
CROSS JOIN dev_append_def dad
LEFT JOIN dev_append da ON d.dev_id = da.dev_id
                    AND dad.append_id = da.append_id;
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining the SQL a little?  I don't 100% understand how the COALESCE statement works with the cross join, nor how it knows to prefer the data from dev_append over the dev_append_def

Comment: The dev_tbl is joined with dev_append_def using a cross join to get all possible values with a default value (this will give you 9 rows (3 row * 3 row)).  The left join to the dev_append keeps all the 9 rows and adds the append_value where it exists, if it does not exist it will be NULL.  The COALESCE will get the first non-null value and use that as the output value, in this case when there is no append_value, it will always have a default_value (at least for the example you gave about as default_value is never null). @AaronBaxter

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your data model but to me it would be more natural if there are no dev_append entries for a device then the default values should be linked to dev_tbl rather than to the dev_append. Anyway as I said I don'k now your requirements so you may be right in what you are doing.

So here is your SELECT that will give you what you want:

```
SELECT dev_tbl.dev_ip, dev_tbl.name, dev_append.append_value, dev_append_def.field_name
  FROM dev_tbl 
  LEFT JOIN dev_append
    ON (dev_tbl.dev_id = dev_append.dev_id) 
  JOIN dev_append_def
    ON (dev_append.append_id = dev_append_def.append_id)

UNION

SELECT dev_tbl.dev_ip, dev_tbl.name, dev_append_def.default_value, dev_append_def.field_name
  FROM dev_tbl
  JOIN dev_append_def 
    ON 1 = 1
 WHERE not exists (select 1 FROM dev_append where dev_append.dev_id = dev_tbl.dev_id)
```

Note I tested it with Oracle but it should work with no problems on SQL Server as well